# Raw PDF structure viewer

Tags: gratis, linux, pdf, gui, pdf-viewer

I want to view the contents of a PDF file - but not so much in the sense of rendering the pages in it. Rather, I want to see the hierarchy of objects, the PDF-structural tags and fields like the encoding, the "Length X Y Z" fields, font descriptors, etc. etc. It would be even better if I could see both the rendered content and the unrendered structure, perhaps with some highlighting of what a piece of the PDF structure has an effect on.

Required features:

- Gratis
- Runs on Linux

Desired features:

- Libre
- Multi-platform
- Supports recent versions of the PDF standard
- Actively maintained
- Non resoure-heavy
- Responds quickly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cpdf -output-json [-output-json-content-streams] in.pdf -o out.json`. `qpdf` has similar functionality but without the ability to parse the content streams. You can alter the JSON file, then round-trip it back to PDF with `cpdf -j in.json -o out.pdf`.

Comment: 1. Link to cpdf website? 2. More information about what cpdf is generally? 3. Can I get the json with the actual content octets? i.e. just the structure?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are:

1. [iText RUPS](https://itextpdf.com/products/rups) ([Source code](https://github.com/itext/i7j-rups))
2. [XFINIUM.PDF Inspector](https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-inspector/xfinium-pdf-inspector-features.html)

Each one covers some of the features you are interested in.

Note: I work for the company that develops the [XFINIUM.PDF Inspector](https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-inspector/xfinium-pdf-inspector-features.html)

Comment: XFINIUM.PDF Inspector is not open source but it is free both for personal and commercial use. The XFINIUM.PDF library is a different product.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry, I misread the website I guess.

Comment: So, does XFINIUM inspector run on Linux? I only see a Windows download.

Comment: No, just Windows

Comment: Well, I specifically asked for something which works on Linux. That's part of the problem with closed-source software, you're stuck with whatever platform they were originally built for.